# PUXAR O NUMERO DO RESULTADO DO BANCO DE DADOS

Tags: php, html, login

Boa tarde,

Estou escrevendo um codigo em Php, onde quero fazer um sistema de validação de login, a conexao com o meu database foi iniciada, porem quando executo a query de chamar o resultado que é "0" ou "1", não esta retornando o numero, esta dando erro.

Abaixo o meu codigo:

```css
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Caixa Rapido</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bulma.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
</head>

<body>
    <section class="hero is-success is-fullheight">
        <div class="hero-body">
            <div class="container has-text-centered">
                <div class="column is-4 is-offset-4">
                    <h3 class="title has-text-grey">Sistema de Login</h3>
                    <h3 class="title has-text-grey">Caixa Rapido</a></h3>
                    
                    <div class="notification is-danger">
                      <p>ERRO: Usuário ou senha inválidos.</p>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="box">
                        <form action="teste.php" method="POST">
                            <div class="field">
                                <div class="control">
                                    <input name="usuario" name="text" class="input is-large" placeholder="Seu usuário" autofocus="">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="field">
                                <div class="control">
                                    <input name="senha" class="input is-large" type="password" placeholder="Sua senha">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="button is-block is-link is-large is-fullwidth">Entrar</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
include('conexao.php');

if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])) {
 header('Location: index.php');
 exit();
}

$login = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);

$query = "select usuario from usuario where usuario = '{$login}' and senha = md5('{$senha}')";

$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row == 1) {
 $_SESSION['usuario'] = $login;
 header('Location: painel.php');
 exit();
} else {
 $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
 header('Location: index.php');
 exit();
}

?>
```

, preciso que faça a validação para que retorne o numero da tabela e entao eu faça a validação se ele vai logar ou nao!

Answer (score -1):

Olá, boa tarde!

Primeiramente, qual erro está dando?
Sempre que for postar algum código, e ele lhe trouxer um erro, coloque-o na pergunta, muitas vezes a solução está no Erro.

Faça dessa forma e nós avise o resultado.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('conexao.php');

if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

$login = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);
$cryptPass = md5($senha);

$query = "select usuario from usuario where usuario = '$login' and senha = '$cryptPass'";

$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row == 1) {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $login;
    header('Location: painel.php');
    exit();
} else {
    $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

?>
```